# git checkout removedFile in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

What is the Mercurial equivalent of the command `git checkout removedFile`? The word removedFile means the removal by the basic-shell `rm` -command, not by `git rm` -command.

Comment: Oh! You're just asking "How do I get back a file I deleted but didn't remove from version control"?  That would have been much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hg revert removedFile
```

should put your missing file back.

Answer (score 0):

What does `git checkout removedFile` do for you?  For me it give a nice, sensible error:

```
ry4an@four:~$ git init test
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/ry4an/test/.git/
ry4an@four:~$ cd test/
ry4an@four:~/test$ echo this > file
ry4an@four:~/test$ git add file
ry4an@four:~/test$ git commit
[master (root-commit) 1b017c5] file added
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file
ry4an@four:~/test$ git rm file
rm 'file'
ry4an@four:~/test$ git commit
[master ec695d4] dsdfsdf
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
 delete mode 100644 file
ry4an@four:~/test$ git checkout file
error: pathspec 'file' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

If you're asking how you can view the contents of a removed files `hg cat` is a fine command to do it, and you can find a revision id using `hg log removedFile`.

Comment: ...I did not mean `$ git rm something` but `$ rm something` by removedFile i.e. a tracked file that is removed from the fs still in git-tracking and I want to get it back.

Comment: Sounds like you just meant "how do I undelete a file I just deleted". That's easy and @splattered bits has your answer.